# What is the most efficient way to deserialize huge JSON responses into POJOs using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, vert.x

I have a Vert.x/Java web service that makes a REST call to another service and receives a paginated response that looks similar to the following:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "count": 500,
    "totalPages": 279,
    "totalResources": 139255,
    "next": "https://some-service.com/some-endpoint?next=(some-hash)"
  },
  "objects": [
   {
     // About 200 fields per "object" mixed in various levels of nesting,
     // only about 10 of which I want to deserialize
     "model": {
       "A field": "A value"
     },
     "topLevelField": "value",
     "someMoreNestedData": {
       // ...
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

The maximum response size of 500 "objects" is around 4-5MB, or about 100k lines of text. After receiving the response, I want to use Jackson to deserialize the array of objects into a flattened data model that consists of the 10 fields per object that my system cares about, discarding the rest. I also need to record the pagination information in the 'pagination' node.

I've implemented the deserialization using two classes that are very similar to these (Lombok annotations omitted to save space):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RawResponse {
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer count;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer totalPages;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer totalResources;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String next;
    @JsonProperty("objects")
    private List<MyCustomObject> products;

    @JsonSetter("pagination")
    public void deserializePaginationNode(Map<String,Object> paginationNode) {
        if (MapUtils.isEmpty(paginationNode)) {
           log.error("Failed to deserialize pagination node: {}", Arrays.toString(paginationNode.entrySet().toArray()));
           return;
        }

        this.count = (Integer) paginationNode.get("count");
        this.totalPages = (Integer) paginationNode.get("totalPages");
        this.totalResources = (Integer) paginationNode.get("totalResources");
        this.next = (String) paginationNode.get("next");
    }
```

Within `MyCustomObject`, I use `@JsonIgnore` annotations in conjunction with `@JsonSetter("node name")` to force Jackson to use my methods to deserialize:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyCustomObject {
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<String> someField;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String anotherField;

    // ...

    @JsonSetter("model")
    public void deserializeModelNode(Map<String,Object> modelNode) {
        if (MapUtils.isEmpty(modelOfferingNode)) {
            log.error("Failed to deserialize model node: {}", Arrays.toString(modelOfferingNode.entrySet().toArray()));
            return;
        }

        this.field = (List<String>) modelNode.get("field");
        this.anotherField = (String) modelOfferingNode.get("anotherField");
    }
```

This approach works, but I'm curious if there's a more efficient implementation that achieves the same result of flattening a complex data structure of ~200 fields at various nested levels into a flat structure using Jackson. For example, I know you can use `@JsonDeserialize` and write a lower-level deserializer that works with more primitive data types like `JsonNode`, etc. Does anyone know of a good alternative?

Comment: Do you have to use json? You may want to consider binary encoding/decoding - or protobuf combined with the streaming capabilities of grpc

Comment: In this context I do need to stick with JSON processing because I'm integrating with an existing service. The idea of gRPC and protocol buffers is really interesting but I'm more looking to see if there's a more efficient deserialization implementation using Jackson and JSON than what I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parsing Large JSON Files using Jackson Streaming API Example](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/03/parsing-large-json-files-using-jackson.html)

> Jackson's Streaming API. Jackson is one of the most popular JSON
>   processing framework and provides three main model to parse and
>   process JSON data including Streaming API, data binding and tree
>   model. Out of these three, Streaming works at lowest level and can be
>   used to parse huge JSON response upto even giga bytes of size

Comment: I think this is the closest answer to the question which was about the most efficient way to parse using Jackson. Thanks!

Comment: If it is okay to you , it is my pleasure  , Welcome dear

Comment: @daniel-kesner fyi the Vert.x JSON parser is built on top of the Jackson streaming API and 1/ simplifies its usage 2/ works well with other Vert.x APIs

Answer (score 1):

If you must process a large amount of data, consider using the [Vert.x JSON parser](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_json_parser)

You will have to switch between the object value and event mode while processing the response buffers: that will let you determine if there's a next page while making the objects data processing easier.